# the program runs but when i type in my value it doesnt do anything . this is a game of rock paper scissors

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a game of rock paper scissors.

The program runs, but when I type in my value it doesn't do anything.

Here's my code:

```
import random

def play():
    user = input("whats your choice? 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors\n")
    computer = random.choice(["r", "p", "s"])

    if user == computer:
        return "its a tie"

    if is_win(user, computer):
        return "you won!"

    return "you lost!"

def is_win(player, opponent) :
    if (player == "r" and opponent == "s") or (player == "s" and opponent == "p")  or (player== "p" and opponent == "r"):
        return True

play()
```

Answer (score 0):

It does run. But you are not printing anything.

You must print what the `play()` function returns. Then only it prints one of the return statements.

```
print(play())
```

Comment: thank you so much you have no idea how much it helped me

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the answers above, you can either print the result, like `print("You won!")` or print the call to the play function like `print(play())`.
This should work.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly. It is just that you aren't making use of the returned value. When you use `return` in the function, you need to either define a variable where you call the function (if you want to use it later) or you can just use `print(your_function())` to print the returned value.

So you need to do:

```
print(play())
```

Or if you want to use it later:

```
val1=play()
print(val1)
```